# Python doesn't find module

Tags: python, import, module

I have installed 'pyserial' and 'serial' module after realizing I don't need the 'serial' module which I uninstall. I run on Python 3.8.

After a lot of trials and errors with different code I found on the internet I keep having the same error which is "AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'tools'"

Here is my code, which import some package and display the module of the 'serial' library :

```
import os
import sys
import serial
import pkgutil

package=serial

for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(package.__path__):
    print ("Found submodule %s (is a package: %s)" % (modname, ispkg))
print(serial)
print(serial.tools)
os.system("pause")
```

Here is my output :

```
C:\Users\ratchet>C:/Users/ratchet/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe d:/Documents/Code/USBCom.py
Found submodule aio (is a package: False)
Found submodule rfc2217 (is a package: False)
Found submodule rs485 (is a package: False)
Found submodule serialcli (is a package: False)
Found submodule serialjava (is a package: False)
Found submodule serialposix (is a package: False)
Found submodule serialutil (is a package: False)
Found submodule serialwin32 (is a package: False)
Found submodule threaded (is a package: True)
Found submodule tools (is a package: True)
Found submodule urlhandler (is a package: True)
Found submodule win32 (is a package: False)
<module 'serial' (namespace)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Documents/Code/USBCom.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(serial.tools)
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'tools'
```

So I'm assuming my serial module is imported and the module 'tools' do exist but I still don't understand why it keep telling me this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting the line `import serial.tools` if you want to `print(serial.tools)`.

Comment: Why would that be the case?

Comment: I've edited my answer to prevent implying that there aren't other ways to get a print out of `serial.tools`.

Comment: Ok thanks you, actually this was the code I was using after 1 hour and try and retry. What I was trying to do is to use the function 'serial.tools.list_ports.comports()' but i dont understand why it only work when i'm importing by 'import serial.tools.list_ports.comports' and not when I do 'import serial'. Shouldn't the 'import serial' import all the module of serial ?

Comment: Only if the package `serial` imports `serial.tools.list_ports.comports` in its `__init__.py` file. This effectively ensures that random modules are encapsulated and aren't exposed at the top level package unless the package maintainer wanted that.